# copying multiple char* into one char* variables C language

Tags: c

How can i copy multiple char* variables into one char* at single instance operation.

say i have

char* text1 = "Hello";

char* text2 = "World";

i want to copy text1, text2 and '2' and "12345" into char* text3 in single function call.

Comment: possible duplicate: stackoverflow.com/questions/968316/concatenating-strings-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char text3[100];
sprintf( text3, "%s%s%s%s", text1, text2, "2", "12345" );
```

Comment: +1: Or `sprintf( text3, "%s%s212345", text1, text2);` if you're feeling parsimonious with processor cycles :)

Comment: I'd rather use snprintf for security reason or use the format string to limit the amount of characters

Comment: @iSIght: If you use sprintf, please check the lenght of your input strings. You'll run into buffer overruns otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

To do that in a ***single*** function call, you will need to have `asprintf()` available on your platform (or, a library implementation of the same). Most modern C libraries offer it, however you may have to enable it as an extension via the preprocessor.

A linux centric example of what you want (which is, I believe to return an allocated / combined string):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* Telling the compiler we want extensions */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char *text1 = "foo";
   char *text2 = "bar";
   char *text3 = NULL;
   int bytes_printed = 0;

   bytes_printed = asprintf(&text3, "%s%s123456789", text1, text2);
   if (bytes_printed < 0 || text3 == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Asprintf failed to allocate memory!\n");
      return 1;
   }

   printf("Asprintf printed %d bytes to text3, which is %s\n",
      bytes_printed, text3);
   free(text3);
   return 0;
}
```

That's the only way I can think of doing it in a ***single*** function call, returning an allocated string.

To make sure its portable, you should probably use a library implementation of it in your tree, something like `my_asprintf()`, which deals effectively with systems that do not offer it.

You can pull it right out of the C library sources of glibc, I believe BSD, even new operating systems like HelenOS offer it.

Answer (score 2):

This automatically resizes `string3` so it can hold the output without buffer overflows

```
const char * string1 = "Hello";
const char * string2 = "World";
char * string3 = NULL;
size_t string3_size = snprintf(NULL,0,"%s%s%s",string1,string2,"1234");
string3 = realloc(string3,string3_size+1); // +1 for '\0'
snprintf(string3,string3_size+1,"%s%s%s",string1,string2,"1234");
```

Comment: For something different really, it helps if `string3` has already been defined. Feel free to replace the realloc line with `char * string3=malloc(string3_size+1);`.

Comment: ... which is basically ... asprintf() :)

Comment: but `snprintf` is C99, so this is an easy way to implement the fallback `asprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

### sprintf

---

**This should do the trick :**

```
sprintf(test3, "%s%s%s%s", text1, text2, "2" , "12345");
```

GoodLUCK!!
- CVS

Answer (score 0):

try this 
strcat() function:

when you combine two strings, you add the characters of one string to the end of other string. This process is called concatenation. The strcat() function joins 2 strings together. It takes the following form

strcat(string1,string2)

string1 & string2 are character arrays. When the function strcat is executed string2 is appended to string1. the string at string2 remains unchanged.

Example

strcpy(string1,”sri”);
strcpy(string2,”Bhagavan”);
Printf(“%s”,strcat(string1,string2);

From the above program segment the value of string1 becomes sribhagavan. The string at str2 remains unchanged as bhagawan.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
char* text1 = "Hello";
char* text2 = "World";
char* phrase = (char *)malloc((char)*15);
snprintf(phrase, 15, "%s %s", text1, text2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf function and print all strings to result string.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you not realize here is that `"string"` in C is an expression that evaluates to a single char pointer towards a `'s'` character which is statically allocated in memory. Which has a `'t'` in the next address, then a `'r'`, all down to `'g'` and then after that a `null` character. That's how strings work in C, that's how library functions deal with them. They just traverse them until they've found `null`.

So in this case, what you want is to remove the last `null` from `"Hello"` and just replace it with the rest. `strcat` does that, it takes pointers to characters followed by other characters, and finally a null-character. And returns a new pointer to another char which is pointing towards the start of their concatenation in memory.